# Manipulate Bytes like Java in PHP

Tags: java, php, string, byte

I have a Java function and I need an equivalent function in PHP. I'm using this to parse a MD5 hash if that helps.

```
public static byte[] asBin(String paramString)
{
    if (paramString.length() < 1)
      return null;
    byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[paramString.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < paramString.length() / 2; i++) {
      int j = Integer.parseInt(paramString.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 1), 16);
      int k = Integer.parseInt(paramString.substring(i * 2 + 1, i * 2 + 2), 16);

      arrayOfByte[i] = ((byte)(j * 16 + k));
    }
    return arrayOfByte;
}
```

For now I got this, but isn't outputing the same.

```
function asBin($str){
    if($str == "") return null;
    $bytes = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str) / 2; $i++){
        $j = intval(substr($str, $i * 2, $i * 2 + 1), 16);
        $k = intval(substr($str, $i * 2 + 1, $i * 2 + 2), 16);
        $bytes[$i] = intval($j * 16 + $k);
    }
    return $bytes;
}
```

Comment: Or just use [`hex2bin()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php)

Comment: May be you have the overflow (in java code) when you convert `int` to `byte` ( see  `(byte)(j * 16 + k)`)

Answer (score 0):

**This is answer (your need add some changes in your code)**:

```
function asBin($str) {
    $byte_max = 127;
    $byte_min = -128;
    if($str == "") {
        return null;
    }
    $bytes = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < floor(strlen($str) / 2); $i++){
        $j = intval(substr($str, $i * 2, 1), 16);
        $k = intval(substr($str, $i * 2 + 1, 1), 16);
        $value = $j * 16 + $k;
        // emulation byte-overflow in java
        if ($value > $byte_max) {
            $value = $value - $byte_max + $byte_min - 1;
        }
        $bytes[$i] = $value;
    }
    return $bytes;
}
```

**Details**:

- See how should use php [`string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )`](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php) in documentation.

**Alternative answer**:

Also you may change you function with one map.
Based on your code, possible answer - just generate php map for all pairs of digits:

```
function init_bin_map() {
    $byte_max = 127;
    $byte_min = -128;
    $bin_map = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 15; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j <= 15; $j++) {
            $key = strval(dechex($i)) . strval(dechex($j));
            $value = $i * 16 + $j;
            // emulation of overflow in java
            if ($value > $byte_max) {
                $value = $value - $byte_max + $byte_min - 1;
            }
            $bin_map[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $bin_map;
}

$bin_map = init_bin_map();

function asBin2($str, $bin_map) {
    $str = strtolower($str);
    if($str == "") return null;
    $bytes = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str) - 1; $i += 2) {
        $key = substr($str, $i, 2);
        $bytes[$i/2] = $bin_map[$key];
    }
    return $bytes;
}
```

And we have:

```
$bin_map = array(
    "00" => 0,
    "01" => 1,
    ...
    "80" => -128,
    "81" => -127,
    "82" => -126,
    "83" => -125,
    ...
);
```